# Service Worker save App: Event handler of 'install' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script

Tags: service-worker

The app is not able to download. In Lighthouse I got the issue that the service worker or manifest fails.

I get two warnings, I do not understand :

1. Event handler of `install` event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.
2. Event handler of `fetch` event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.

**App URLS:** @Vimal Patel

**Site:** https://www.kuehroint.com/archenkanzel/archenkanzel-wimbachbruecke.html
**Service Worker .sw** https://www.kuehroint.com/archenkanzel/sw.js (Warnings)
**Manifest Jason** https://www.kuehroint.com/archenkanzel/manifest.json

This script i think is not in use.
https://www.kuehroint.com/archenkanzel/service-worker.js

Console Warnings  in Code Comments :

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
 // Perform install steps
 var CACHE_NAME = 'my-site-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = ['archenkanzel-wimbachbruecke.html'    ,
'     ../xcss/bergtouren.css',
'../icons/kuehr.jpg' 

];

 
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {  /*<-- Event handler of 'install' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script */
 // Perform install steps
 event.waitUntil(
   caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
     .then(function(cache) {
       console.log('Opened cache');
       return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
     })
 );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) { /*<-- Event handler of 'fetch' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.*/
 event.respondWith(
   caches.match(event.request)
     .then(function(response) {
       // Cache hit - return response
       if (response) {
         return response;
       }
       return fetch(event.request);
     }
   )
 );
});
});
```

Comment: Can you share your site url?

Comment: Thank you Vimal Patel :-), i edit the Urls  on Top -> App URLS

Comment: I remember i did some changes i put loading="lazy" to every image could that be a problem ? Other changes i did , i cut out of the app i checked already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your service worker is not installed properly. Below are the few issue in your service worker [Link](https://www.kuehroint.com/archenkanzel/sw.js)

- You have declared "install" event multiple times.
- The first "install" event function is not properly closed. It is closed at the end. This is not valid javascript.

**Solution**:-

- Remove your first install event (on line number 2).
- Make sure your service worker functions are valid javascript functions.

Also make sure every file you add in your cache list should return a 200 response otherwise your install event will fail.

Comment: Thank you Vimal :-)